# JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance in picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem with WildFly 8.1.0

Tags: java, wildfly-8, picketlink

I'm trying to deploy the sample *picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem*, tag v2.7.0.Final (https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/tree/v2.7.0.Final/picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem) in the WildFly 8.1.0, but I'm getting the following error.

How to solve this?

Thanks

```
    20:00:27,995 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war
    20:00:28,000 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war
    20:00:28,107 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Event] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.picketlink.internal.IdentityStoreAutoConfiguration.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    20:00:28,704 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component.SecurityInitializer.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component.SecurityInitializer.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
...
            at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:162) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
            ... 11 more
    Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            ... 27 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: picketlink/JPADSBasedPartitionManager -- service jboss.naming.context.java.picketlink.JPADSBasedPartitionManager
            at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104) [wildfly-naming-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:202) [wildfly-naming-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:233) [wildfly-naming-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:188) [wildfly-naming-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184) [wildfly-naming-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldResourceInjectionServices.resolveResource(WeldResourceInjectionServices.java:186)
            at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldResourceInjectionServices$1.createResource(WeldResourceInjectionServices.java:139)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection.getResourceReference(AbstractResourceInjection.java:44)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection.injectResourceReference(AbstractResourceInjection.java:53)
            at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectEEFields(Beans.java:331)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:59)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:90)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.getReceiver(AbstractMemberProducer.java:128)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:148)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:183)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.createUnderlying(EEResourceProducerField.java:144)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.create(EEResourceProducerField.java:133)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:753)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.getBeanInstance(InstanceImpl.java:86)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:76)
            at org.picketlink.producer.IdentityManagerProducer.init(IdentityManagerProducer.java:102)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:72)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invoke(MethodInjectionPoint.java:66)
            at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.callInitializers(Beans.java:382)
            at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:370)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:60)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:90)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.getReceiver(AbstractMemberProducer.java:128)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:148)
            at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:183)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:789)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
            ... 46 more

    20:00:28,732 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war\".component.SecurityInitializer.START" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war\".component.SecurityInitializer.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
        Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
        Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
        Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: picketlink/JPADSBasedPartitionManager -- service jboss.naming.context.java.picketlink.JPADSBasedPartitionManager"}}
    20:00:28,734 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
    {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war\".component.SecurityInitializer.START" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war\".component.SecurityInitializer.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
        Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
        Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
        Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: picketlink/JPADSBasedPartitionManager -- service jboss.naming.context.java.picketlink.JPADSBasedPartitionManager"}}
    20:00:28,743 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war
    20:00:28,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/PicketLinkQuickstartDS]
    20:00:28,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war (runtime-name: picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war) in 115ms
    20:00:28,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component.AuthorizationChecker.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component.LoginController.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem, service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".deploymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component.SecurityInitializer.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem, service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".deploymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".deploymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".deploymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart]
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".deploymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
    JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".WeldBootstrapService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".WeldStartService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.AccountService.CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.AccountService.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.AccountService.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.AccountService.VIEW."org.jboss.as.quickstarts.picketlink.angularjs.security.service.AccountService".LOCAL (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.AccountService.WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.VIEW."org.jboss.as.quickstarts.picketlink.angularjs.security.model.IdentityModelManager".LOCAL (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.IdentityModelManager.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.JWSTokenProvider.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.JWSTokenProvider.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.JWSTokenProvider.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.MailService.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.MailService.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.MailService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.MailService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.VIEW."org.jboss.as.quickstarts.picketlink.angularjs.service.PersonService".LOCAL (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.PersonService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.RegistrationService.CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.RegistrationService.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.RegistrationService.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.RegistrationService.VIEW."org.jboss.as.quickstarts.picketlink.angularjs.security.service.RegistrationService".LOCAL (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.RegistrationService.WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.RegistrationService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.SecurityInitializer.JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.SecurityInitializer.START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.SecurityInitializer.VIEW."org.jboss.as.quickstarts.picketlink.angularjs.security.SecurityInitializer".LOCAL (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component.SecurityInitializer.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.picketlink.http.internal.PicketLinkServletContextListener".CREATE (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.picketlink.http.internal.PicketLinkServletContextListener".JndiBindingsService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.picketlink.http.internal.PicketLinkServletContextListener".START (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".component."org.picketlink.http.internal.PicketLinkServletContextListener".WeldInstantiator (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".jndiDependencyService (no longer required)
          service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.app.picketlink-angularjs-rest.env (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.mail.gmail (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.BeanManager (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.DefaultContextService (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.DefaultDataSource (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.DefaultManagedExecutorService (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.DefaultManagedThreadFactory (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.EJBContext (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.TimerService (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.UserTransaction (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.env (no longer required)
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module.picketlink-angularjs-rest.picketlink-angularjs-rest.env."org.jboss.as.quickstarts.picketlink.angularjs.service.MailService".session (no longer required)
          service jboss.persistenceunit."picketlink-angularjs-rest.war#primary" (no longer required)
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-angularjs-rest (no longer required)
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./picketlink-angularjs-rest.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (no longer required)
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa-with-subsystem.war".component.SecurityInitializer.START
```

Comment: I haven't used JBoss for quite a while, but have you set `picketlink/JPADSBasedPartitionManager` JNDI name? It seems it can't find that for your JPA datasource.

Comment: Did you come up with any solution for this? I'm also having the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance" error.

Comment: @Twimnox no, sorry. We stopped using JavaEE and consequently Picketlink; switched to Spring..